# Hangindent and justfied multiline text in single cell of table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, indentation, columns, booktabs

I have quite a lot of text that I want to format in a readable manner in a single cell of a table, so I want to use hangindents. But in addition to that I want to make the text justified, but this is not working. If I use `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and then change `\raggedright` to `\justify`, all hell breaks loose.

In order to have the hangindent, I needed to make a `\customnewline` command, to repeat the hangindent (see difference between left and right column).

How can I combine this all, so make the text 'hang' and justified?

Note: It is quite a large table, which I am creating using [Excel2LaTeX](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX), so I would like to make the least amount of changes possible... That's why I changed the columntype.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

% define new column type
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\small \hangindent=1em \raggedright \let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

% define newline to use hangindent on new line
\newcommand{\customnewline}{\newline \hangindent=1em}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Example}
    \begin{tabular}{Y{15em}Y{15em}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{customnewline}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{normal newline}} \\
    \midrule
    A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent \customnewline And there some more text in the same cell that I want to hangindent as well & A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent \newline And there some more text in the same cell that I want to hangindent as well \\
    A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent \customnewline And there some more text in the same cell that I want to hangindent as well & A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent \newline And there some more text in the same cell that I want to hangindent as well \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image: table MVCE example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your objectives aren't entirely clear. E.g., you write "A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent", but the material isn't [fully] justified; instead, it is set ragged-right. Please clarify.

Comment: Well, that is the problem, if I set it to `\justify` in `\newcolumntype`, only half the table shows. So how can I change the column definition in such a way that the text will be justified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a blank line, instead, provided you set up hanging indentation for every paragraph:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

% define new column type
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{%
  >{\small\raggedright\everypar{\hangindent=1em}\arraybackslash}p{#1}%
}

\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{%
  >{\small\everypar{\hangindent=1em}\arraybackslash}p{#1}%
}

% define newline to use hangindent on new line

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{Y{15em}Z{15em}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ragged right} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Justified} \\
\midrule
A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent

And there some more text in the same cell that I want to 
hangindent as well
&
A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent

And there some more text in the same cell that I want to 
hangindent as well
\\
\midrule
A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent

And there some more text in the same cell that I want to 
hangindent as well
&
A lot of text that I want to justify and hangindent

And there some more text in the same cell that I want to 
hangindent as well
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Since I didn't want to add blank lines in all my table cells, I changed my customnewline to break the paragraph; `\newcommand{\customnewline}{\par}`